# HtmlUnit - How do I extract a value from between nested div tags?

Tags: html, nested, htmlunit

I'm trying to make a simple web scraper for a class project and I'm trying to scrape a random facebook page for publicly available information - the pages that a user 'likes'. I'm using HtmlUnit and can get the page to return ok with the relevant information I need. However, I'm having trouble extracting the String from a nested div. Here is the Info I need to extract:

[image]

I need to get a list of all the users 'likes'.

My code so far, which doesn't seem to be working:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
try {
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(URL); //URL is random Facebook page
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

    List<DomElement> divs = page.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(DomElement element : divs){
        if(element.getAttribute("class").equals("mediaPageName")){
            System.out.println(element.getNodeValue());
        }
    }
```

Is it even possible to extract a String which is nested so deep? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: full html (of body) as requested:

```
<body class="timelineLayoutLoggedOutUserProfile timelineLayoutLoggedOut _4lh timelineLayout fbx UIPage_LoggedOut _2gsg gecko win x1 Locale_en_GB" dir="ltr"><div class="_li"><div id="pagelet_bluebar" role="banner"><div id="blueBarDOMInspector" class="_21mm"><div id="blueBarNAXAnchor" class="_4f7n _xxp"><div><div class="loggedout_menubar_container"><div class="clearfix loggedout_menubar"><div class="lfloat _ohe"><h1><a href="/" title="Go to Facebook Home"><i class="fb_logo img sp_9vUokIDmpP8 sx_15c231"><u>Facebook logo</u></i></a></h1></div><div class="menu_login_container rfloat _ohf"><form id="login_form" action="https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1" method="post" onsubmit="return window.Event &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)"><input name="lsd" value="AVpZmDWW" autocomplete="off" type="hidden"><table role="presentation" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td class="html7magic"><label for="email">Email or Phone</label></td><td class="html7magic"><label for="pass">Password</label></td></tr><tr><td><input class="inputtext" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1" type="text"></td><td><input class="inputtext" name="pass" id="pass" tabindex="2" type="password"></td><td><label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" id="loginbutton" for="u_0_0"><input value="Log in" tabindex="4" id="u_0_0" type="submit"></label></td></tr><tr><td class="login_form_label_field"><div><div class="uiInputLabel clearfix uiInputLabelLegacy"><input id="persist_box" name="persistent" value="1" tabindex="3" class="uiInputLabelInput uiInputLabelCheckbox" type="checkbox"><label for="persist_box" class="uiInputLabelLabel">Keep me logged in</label></div><input name="default_persistent" value="0" type="hidden"></div></td><td class="login_form_label_field"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate">Forgotten your password?</a></td></tr></tbody></table><input autocomplete="off" name="timezone" value="0" id="u_0_1" type="hidden"><input name="lgnrnd" value="065157_G5Yp" type="hidden"><input id="lgnjs" name="lgnjs" value="1420815122" type="hidden"><input autocomplete="off" id="locale" name="locale" value="en_GB" type="hidden"><input autocomplete="off" name="next" value="https://www.facebook.com/steven.mcguckin.14" type="hidden"><input value="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" name="qsstamp" type="hidden"></form></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div id="globalContainer" class="uiContextualLayerParent"><div class="fb_content clearfix " id="content" role="main"><div><div id="toolbarContainer" class="hidden_elem"></div><div id="mainContainer"><div id="leftCol"></div><div id="contentCol" class="clearfix hasRightCol"><div id="rightCol" role="complementary"><div id="rightColContent"></div></div><div id="contentArea" role="main"><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_timeline_main_column" data-referrer="pagelet_timeline_main_column" data-gt="{&quot;profile_owner&quot;:&quot;100003774926665&quot;,&quot;ref&quot;:&quot;timeline:timeline&quot;}"><div class="timelineLoggedOutSignUpWithoutCover"><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_loggedout_sign_up" data-referrer="pagelet_loggedout_sign_up"><div class="pam uiBoxOverlay bottomborder"><div class="fsxl fwb">Steven Mcguckin<br> is on Facebook.</div><div class="mvm fsl">To connect with Steven, sign up for Facebook today.</div><a class="uiButton uiButtonSpecial uiButtonLarge" href="/r.php?profile_id=100003774926665&amp;next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsteven.mcguckin.14&amp;friend_or_subscriber=friend" role="button"><span class="uiButtonText">Sign Up</span></a><a class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonLarge" href="/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsteven.mcguckin.14" role="button" name="login"><span class="uiButtonText">Log in</span></a></div></div></div><div class="fbTimelineTopSectionBase _6-d _529n _6_5"><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_above_header_timeline" data-referrer="pagelet_above_header_timeline"></div><div id="above_header_timeline_placeholder"></div><div class="fbTimelineSection mtm fbTimelineTopSection fbTimelineLoggedOutTopSection"><div id="fbProfileCover"><div class="cover" id="u_0_2"><div class="coverEmptyWrap _37fg coverImage coverNoImage" id="fbCoverImageContainer" data-cropped="1"><img class="coverChangeThrobber img" src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yk/r/LOOn0JtHNzb.gif" alt="" height="16" width="16"></div></div><div id="fbTimelineHeadline" class="clearfix"><div class="actions"><div class="_5h60 actionsDropdown" id="pagelet_timeline_profile_actions" data-referrer="pagelet_timeline_profile_actions"></div></div><div class="name"><div class="photoContainer"><div><a class="profilePicThumb" href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=114855338650296&amp;set=a.114854815317015.15000.100003774926665&amp;type=1&amp;source=11" rel="theater"><img class="profilePic img" alt="Steven Mcguckin" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/v/t1.0-1/c46.46.577.577/s160x160/540497_114855338650296_1335437651_n.jpg?oh=8d3b224ef56c50a8a043ce49901e5d5f&amp;oe=556CFE3E&amp;__gda__=1429368453_dff0e7bb5ca2eca91432ccdb97bc5d92"></a></div><meta itemprop="image" content="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/v/t1.0-1/c46.46.577.577/s50x50/540497_114855338650296_1335437651_n.jpg?oh=054f9dc65e6f67982ad9aafe2229cce4&amp;oe=55241D58&amp;__gda__=1429778354_e0db2aeed8623991fe8eb84f7253f0b5"></div><h2 itemprop="name">Steven Mcguckin</h2></div></div></div></div></div><div class="timelineLoggedOutPagelet"><div class="clearfix"><div class="timelineLoggedOutMain lfloat _ohe"><div class="_5h60 allFavorites" id="pagelet_all_favorites" data-referrer="pagelet_all_favorites"><div class="fbTimelineSection mtm timelineFavorites fbTimelineCompactSection"><div class="profileInfoSection" id="favorites"><div class="uiHeader fbTimelineAboutMeHeader"><div class="clearfix uiHeaderTop"><div><h4 class="uiHeaderTitle">Favourites</h4></div></div></div><div class="phs"><table role="presentation" class="mtm _5e7- profileInfoTable _3stp _3stn"><tbody><tr><th class="label"><div class="labelContainer">Music</div></th><td class="data"><div class="mediaRowWrapper"><ul class="uiList pbl mediaRow _509- _4ki _6-h _704 _6-i"><li><div class="mediaPortrait"><div class="profilePicContainer"><div class="blackBackground"></div><img class="photo img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p80x80/407738_10150488772887362_814101701_n.jpg?oh=25075b281b5dcecf3ab6e63c07b984c5&amp;oe=556D1F73&amp;__gda__=1428710219_9c8849d34cea33b428bce751dd612694" title="Queen" height="75" width="75"><div class="likeButtonContainer"></div></div><a class="mediaRowItem" href="https://www.facebook.com/Queen"><div class="mediaPageName">Queen</div></a></div></li><li><div class="mediaPortrait"><div class="profilePicContainer"><div class="blackBackground"></div><img class="photo img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/p80x80/1395394_10151745021285264_2126877109_n.jpg?oh=4688157fb7cdcba5ae00faa4d6d77911&amp;oe=55240FFB&amp;__gda__=1430011181_16a4e7ade29650e8615d1b95b659a928" title="Metallica" height="75" width="75"><div class="likeButtonContainer"></div></div><a class="mediaRowItem" href="https://www.facebook.com/Metallica"><div class="mediaPageName">Metallica</div></a></div></li><li><div class="mediaPortrait"><div class="profilePicContainer"><div class="blackBackground"></div><img class="photo img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc3/v/t1.0-1/p80x80/537033_10151701254952981_2043344916_n.jpg?oh=2731c9db543d1fba29decf94729585a2&amp;oe=552B2377&amp;__gda__=1429429046_381861d8e3d2283b0da76c45e0339f37" title="Creedence Clearwater Revival" height="75" width="75"><div class="likeButtonContainer"></div></div><a class="mediaRowItem" href="https://www.facebook.com/CCR"><div class="mediaPageName">Creedence Clearwater Revival</div></a></div></li><li><div class="mediaPortrait"><div class="profilePicContainer"><div class="blackBackground"></div><img class="photo img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/p80x80/10406831_10152503824276088_447997052969832982_n.jpg?oh=f15bc83a65fc50aba5f4d24b6626fc65&amp;oe=553CC6D5&amp;__gda__=1429526616_03d5eda2091b5254eae8addf2319787d" title="Jimi Hendrix" height="75" width="75"><div class="likeButtonContainer"></div></div><a class="mediaRowItem" href="https://www.facebook.com/JimiHendrix"><div class="mediaPageName">Jimi Hendrix</div></a></div></li></ul></div></td></tr><tr class="spacer"><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><th class="label"><div class="labelContainer">Games</div></th><td class="data"><div class="mediaRowWrapper"><ul class="uiList pbl mediaRow _509- _4ki _6-h _704 _6-i"><li><div class="mediaPortrait"><div class="profilePicContainer"><div class="blackBackground"></div><img class="photo img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/p80x80/10350338_10155107236685556_4391846249065841385_n.jpg?oh=179afe33d10d68af31cb3d3df577cb9d&amp;oe=55322992&amp;__gda__=1430299694_d3261137fb42061b4a6eeb1833e9a30e" title="League of Legends" height="75" width="75"><div class="likeButtonContainer"></div></div><a class="mediaRowItem" href="https://www.facebook.com/leagueoflegends"><div class="mediaPageName">League of Legends</div></a></div></li><li><div class="mediaPortrait"><div class="profilePicContainer"><div class="blackBackground"></div><img class="photo img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/p80x80/10857718_692946477488149_3478982491235992102_n.jpg?oh=a01453157d14b980487f9604cc2e1ef0&amp;oe=55400821&amp;__gda__=1429135421_e0844416b4710a0be857071a0e779c6e" title="League of Legends - Brasil" height="75" width="75"><div class="likeButtonContainer"></div></div><a class="mediaRowItem" href="https://www.facebook.com/LeagueofLegendsBrasil"><div class="mediaPageName">League of Legends - Brasil</div></a></div></li></ul></div></td></tr><tr class="spacer"><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><th class="label"><div class="labelContainer">Other</div></th><td class="data"><div class="uiCollapsedList uiCollapsedListHidden uiCollapsedListNoSeparate pagesListData" id="u_0_5"><span class="visible"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/BestOfVines">Best Vines</a>, <a href="https://www.facebook.com/epicvinesofficial">Epic Vines</a></span></div></td></tr><tr class="spacer"><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div></div><div class="timelineLoggedOutRight rfloat _ohf"><div class="fbTimelineSection mtm fbTimelineCompactSection"><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_search" data-referrer="pagelet_search"><div><div class="uiHeader fbTimelineAboutMeHeader"><div class="clearfix uiHeaderTop"><div><h4 class="uiHeaderTitle">Wrong <a href="/public/Steven-Mcguckin">Steven Mcguckin</a>? Try Again</h4></div></div></div><div class="phs"><form class="mvl mhm pts" method="get" action="/search.php" onsubmit="return window.Event &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)" id="u_0_8"><div class="uiComboInput"><input class="inputtext" value="Steven Mcguckin" name="q" type="text"><label class="comboButton uiButton" for="u_0_7"><input value="Search" id="u_0_7" type="submit"></label></div></form></div></div></div></div><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_people_same_name" data-referrer="pagelet_people_same_name"><div><div class="fbTimelineSection mtm fbTimelineCompactSection"><div class="uiHeader fbTimelineAboutMeHeader"><div class="clearfix uiHeaderTop"><div><h4 class="uiHeaderTitle">Others named Steven Mcguckin</h4></div></div></div><ul class="uiList phs pts profile-friends _4kg"><li><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" href="https://www.facebook.com/steven.mcguckin.1238" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c189.47.583.583/s50x50/523313_109653462547302_1582598403_n.jpg?oh=bd1e7485d44e684999409f897443a767&amp;oe=552EF4EE&amp;__gda__=1433244975_de9b54ed6b21e48002dc07b56c34cfe4" alt="Steven Mcguckin"></a><div class="_42ef"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:50px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="profileFriendsContent"><div class="profileFriendsText"><strong><a href="https://www.facebook.com/steven.mcguckin.1238">Steven Mcguckin</a></strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></li><li><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" href="https://www.facebook.com/steven.mcguckin.102" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/10888641_1558468697729470_1574411548062292882_n.jpg?oh=ac4263182f6baa14ff9c7f8f9a2d4912&amp;oe=552DE084&amp;__gda__=1428276923_68104f6666539fff8416bb758a245484" alt="Steven Mcguckin"></a><div class="_42ef"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:50px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="profileFriendsContent"><div class="profileFriendsText"><strong><a href="https://www.facebook.com/steven.mcguckin.102">Steven Mcguckin</a></strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></li></ul></div><div class="fbTimelineSection mtm fbTimelineCompactSection"><div class="uiHeader fbTimelineAboutMeHeader fbTimelineInternalHeader"><div class="clearfix uiHeaderTop"><div><h4 class="uiHeaderTitle">Others with a similar name</h4></div></div></div><ul class="uiList phs pts profile-friends _4kg"><li><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" href="https://www.facebook.com/steven.woltz" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc3/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/1378740_728203910527490_87439746_n.jpg?oh=78c3fee8fb2a5fe8232a7e3861920541&amp;oe=5537F185&amp;__gda__=1428474249_20af1867912771f1e4fb29342863b18c" alt="Steven Woltz"></a><div class="_42ef"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:50px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="profileFriendsContent"><div class="profileFriendsText"><strong><a href="https://www.facebook.com/steven.woltz">Steven Woltz</a></strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></li><li><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" href="https://www.facebook.com/steven.post.12" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/10922431_10204796417863129_9212432233500209728_n.jpg?oh=b2e4752277fe32ae57cefc07ed11a4fd&amp;oe=552812A2&amp;__gda__=1430023335_d7784ee124e6c04636aa22daf9702168" alt="Steven Post"></a><div class="_42ef"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:50px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="profileFriendsContent"><div class="profileFriendsText"><strong><a href="https://www.facebook.com/steven.post.12">Steven Post</a></strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></li><li><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" href="https://nl-nl.facebook.com/steven.driesen.98" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/1151013_10202074356919805_986387285_n.jpg?oh=bf601dd1ccc03cfe4cfd27cd2d56b70c&amp;oe=55374CEE&amp;__gda__=1430285150_d3f8b42a1723db70c1e301b62b46e45a" alt="Steven Driesen"></a><div class="_42ef"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:50px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="profileFriendsContent"><div class="profileFriendsText"><strong><a href="https://nl-nl.facebook.com/steven.driesen.98">Steven Driesen</a></strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></li><li><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/steven.sutherland.35" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c107.31.391.391/s50x50/20674_100488083317683_2223071_n.jpg?oh=19a4fa1623a204ffc1f92958dc89a440&amp;oe=5524D113&amp;__gda__=1429645973_595004c5b58702edc2c70de8701c3851" alt="Steven Sutherland"></a><div class="_42ef"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:50px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="profileFriendsContent"><div class="profileFriendsText"><strong><a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/steven.sutherland.35">Steven Sutherland</a></strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></li><li><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" href="https://www.facebook.com/stevekapaun" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c0.8.50.50/p50x50/1618522_10152293141074122_756396209_n.jpg?oh=9590e197d0633cecd811b7b71ed0b7e7&amp;oe=5536BC7E&amp;__gda__=1428456951_b07ee3c50c1f7edd2b8800e27e619c02" alt="Steven Kapaun"></a><div class="_42ef"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:50px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="profileFriendsContent"><div class="profileFriendsText"><strong><a href="https://www.facebook.com/stevekapaun">Steven Kapaun</a></strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></li><li><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" href="https://www.facebook.com/jhon.steven.549" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/c8.0.50.50/p50x50/25318_101094259928349_814007_n.jpg?oh=d71ec1eac09fff19f0ce81de6d123dbf&amp;oe=55362389&amp;__gda__=1429253978_2865a36a514b16deef4211b77eb67641" alt="Jhon Steven"></a><div class="_42ef"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:50px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="profileFriendsContent"><div class="profileFriendsText"><strong><a href="https://www.facebook.com/jhon.steven.549">Jhon Steven</a></strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></li><li><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/steven.frati.1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c50.50.621.621/s50x50/430524_4736301724833_48989225_n.jpg?oh=5ff629341422d0a235680431f0317a35&amp;oe=552DE9B6&amp;__gda__=1428809958_b2d18695108e92b95a00c4ff38c5b356" alt="Steven Frati"></a><div class="_42ef"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:50px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="profileFriendsContent"><div class="profileFriendsText"><strong><a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/steven.frati.1">Steven Frati</a></strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></li><li><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" href="https://www.facebook.com/steven.smyth.18" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/1526390_10201844128410526_103308447_n.jpg?oh=3ea17bdb075699741ad4c24f07115ad2&amp;oe=552089EF&amp;__gda__=1428354601_d14a13e379dd14f8a9c267a15336de60" alt="Steven Smyth"></a><div class="_42ef"><div class="_6a"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:50px"></div><div class="_6a _6b"><div class="profileFriendsContent"><div class="profileFriendsText"><strong><a href="https://www.facebook.com/steven.smyth.18">Steven Smyth</a></strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></li></ul></div></div></div><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_contact" data-referrer="pagelet_contact"><div class="_4qm1"><div class="clearfix _h71"><span class="_h72 lfloat _ohe _50f8 _50f7">Contact Information</span></div><ul class="uiList fbProfileEditExperiences _4kg _4ks"><li class="_2pi4"><span class="_3-9b _50f8 _50f4">No contact info to show</span></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div id="bottomContent"></div></div></div></div></div><div id="pageFooter" data-referrer="page_footer"><div id="contentCurve"></div><div role="contentinfo" aria-label="Facebook site links"><table class="uiGrid _51mz navigationGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr class="_51mx"><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/r.php" title="Sign up for Facebook">Sign Up</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/login/" title="Log in to Facebook">Log in</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/mobile/?ref=pf" title="Check out Facebook Mobile.">Mobile</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/find-friends?ref=pf" title="Find anyone on the web.">Find Friends</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/badges/?ref=pf" title="Embed a Facebook badge on your website.">Badges</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/directory/people/" title="Browse our people directory.">People</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/directory/pages/" title="Browse our Pages directory.">Pages</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/places/" title="Check out popular places on Facebook.">Places</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm _51mw"><a href="/games/" title="Check out Facebook games.">Games</a></td></tr><tr class="_51mx"><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/directory/places/" title="Browse our places directory.">Locations</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/facebook" accesskey="8" title="Read our blog, discover the resource centre and find job opportunities.">About</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/campaign/landing.php?placement=pflo&amp;campaign_id=402047449186&amp;extra_1=auto" title="Advertise on Facebook">Create Advert</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/pages/create/?ref_type=sitefooter" title="Create a Page">Create Page</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="https://developers.facebook.com/?ref=pf" title="Develop on our platform.">Developers</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/careers/?ref=pf" title="Make your next career move to our brilliant company.">Careers</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/privacy/explanation" title="Learn about your privacy and Facebook.">Privacy</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/help/cookies/?ref=sitefooter" title="Learn about cookies and Facebook.">Cookies</a></td><td class="_51m- hLeft plm _51mw"><a href="/policies/?ref=pf" accesskey="9" title="Review our terms and policies.">Terms</a></td></tr><tr class="_51mx"><td class="_51m- hLeft plm"><a href="/help/?ref=pf" accesskey="0" title="Visit our Help Centre.">Help</a></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="mvl copyright"><div><span> Facebook © 2015</span><div class="fsm fwn fcg"><a rel="dialog" ajaxify="/settings/language/language/?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsteven.mcguckin.14&amp;source=TOP_LOCALES_DIALOG" title="Use Facebook in another language." href="#" role="button">English (UK)</a></div></div></div></div></div></div><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/(function(){function si_cj(m){setTimeout(function(){new Image().src="https:\/\/error.facebook.com\/common\/scribe_endpoint.php?c=si_clickjacking&t=4737"+"&m="+m;},5000);}if(top!=self && !false){try{if(parent!=top){throw 1;}var si_cj_d=["apps.facebook.com","apps.beta.facebook.com"];var href=top.location.href.toLowerCase();for(var i=0;i<si_cj_d.length;i++){if (href.indexOf(si_cj_d[i])>=0){throw 1;}}si_cj("3 https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/public\/Steven-Mcguckin");}catch(e){si_cj("1 \thttps:\/\/www.facebook.com\/public\/Steven-Mcguckin");window.document.write("\u003Cstyle>body * {display:none !important;}\u003C\/style>\u003Ca href=\"#\" onclick=\"top.location.href=window.location.href\" style=\"display:block !important;padding:10px\">\u003Ci class=\"img sp_qIp5uuAkFU5 sx_7692ea\" style=\"display:block !important\">\u003C\/i>Go to Facebook.com\u003C\/a>");/*lnHZrpcW*/}}}())/*]]>*/</script>
</body>
```

Comment: It is possible. Can you paste the html code on the question instead of the image? Paste the full html.

Comment: I've added in the html

Comment: I would let the browser show me the xpath to the 'div' and use this in HtmlUnit to access it. That seams to be simpler than searching for the attribut value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by ditching HtmlUnit altogether and using Selenium instead, which appears to be much better at handling the js. The following code using Selenium will extract the information I was looking for flawlessly:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get(URL); //The Facebook URL I'm trying to scrape

long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;

while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
    WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.className("mediaPageName"));

    if(div.isDisplayed()){
        break;
    }
}

List<WebElement> allDivs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='mediaPageName']")); 
for(WebElement likes : allDivs){
    System.out.println(likes.getText());
}

driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

```
            HtmlElement element = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@id='favorites']/div[2]/table/tbody[2]/tr/td/div/ul/li[2]/div/a/div");
            String text = element.getTextContent();
```

Comment: I tried that but 
    element = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@id='favorites']/div[2]/table/tbody[2]/tr/td/div/ul/li[2]/div/a/div");

returns 'null'.

Comment: @Highway62  I got that xpath from the html code you pasted. Get the xpath while the full webpage is loaded in your browser and try it with that xpath. If that does not work, print the html code from htmlunit and then get the xpath from the html code that htmlunit rendered.

Comment: Tried it using the exact xpath I got from the element:

HtmlElement element = page.getFirstByXPath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody[2]/tr[1]/td/div/ul/li[2]/div/a/div");

but that too returned null

Comment: Did you generate that from the HTMLUnit page? try putting //html..... instead of /html.....  pretty much add a slash to the front and see what happens. If it does not work, you can give me the URL and I can try to make it work

Comment: I was just using a random facebook page, trying to scrape the pages they like as Strings, eg "league of legends", "metallica" for this page: https://www.facebook.com/steven.mcguckin.14

Comment: @Highway62 you can always use Regular Expression.

Comment: I solved the problem by using Selenium instead of HtmlUnit. It turned out just as simple as the way I had been doing it in HtmlUnit, but Selenium appears to work much better. Thanks for your help anyway.